# Как std::iostream узнаёт, когда надо делать flush()?

Tags: c++, потоки-данных, io

Как `std::iostream` узнаёт, когда надо делать `flush()` (не указывая это вручную манипуляторами или явным вызовом)?

Судя по документации, [деструктор](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_iostream/~basic_iostream) класса, а также [деструктор](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/~basic_ostream) базового `std::ostream` класса этого не делают. Единственное, [что удалось найти](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/flush), это явный вызов `std::cout.flush()` при завершении программы либо при чтении/записи из/в `std::cin`, `std::cerr`, которые связаны (tied) с `std::cout`. Распространяются ли эти случаи на произвольный `std::iostream`?

Comment: Вообще-то специально деструктор этого, может, и не делает, но он закрывает поток, а закрытие фотока/файла означает сброс всех буферов...

Comment: @Harry под потоком вы понимаете `std::basic_streambuf` или что?

Comment: @kkk, «поток» — это std::*stream... и да, он вызывает `flush()` или аналогичное действие при закрытии//деструкции, но чтобы доподлинно подтвердить это надо перечитать стандарт, а не вторичные доки...

Comment: std::cout не делает flash, flash делает std::endl;

Comment: да рАспространяются на произвольный

Comment: как буфер заканчивается, тогда и `flush`. Непонятен вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

flush() вызывается endl - ом, (поэтому, кстати, endl тормозит программу), также при окончании программы (или потока) делается flush. Пишу ответом потому, что репутации не хватает на комменты